# Java script un-understood command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im fairly new to JS, and I've the following `if` statement. When I debug it, I see that in `sMethod`, I have value **"flush"**, and in `oImpl` I've the object in the png below, and when I debug it with those values, it runs the `alert`. Why????

In `oImpl`, I don't see the value in the debugger when I expand the object (to the first level), so what am I missing here?
I thought if th

```
if (oImpl[sMethod]) {
alert("test")
}
```

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: You might be inspecting the wrong object/ right object at the wrong time..?

Comment: @Todd-Im debugging this code and when I thought that if the "flush" is not in oImpl it will not enter to the alert...so what this code should do if (oImpl[sMethod])???maybe I miss something...

Comment: You are asking why `if (oImpl["flush"]) {` is true? So debug and find out what `console.log(sMethod, oImpl[sMethod]);` is

Comment: In JavaScript `oImpl["flush"]` is interpreted as `true`, so the alert inside the if statement runs.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek-Thanks but I've the flush attr inside the proto object not in the first level object so what does the if (oImpl[sMethod]) do?search for value on all the tree obj or the first level and the proto obj ????

Comment: @TJ-Thanks but I've the "flush" property inside the proto object not in the first level object so what does the if (oImpl[sMethod]) do?search for value on all the tree obj or the first level and the proto obj

Answer (score 2):

And if expand prototype (in this case the property "**proto**"), there is a method "flush"?

Comment: yes in the proto there is property flush,so what exactly this code do if (oImpl[sMethod] ) ?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The OP basically asked "how can `oImpl` have a `flush` property, seeing it doesn't have it when printed by console.log?". The answer, while being phrased as a question, tells the OP to look at the prototype, since it's the most likely place for it to be defined. (and it was indeed)

Comment: If the prototype method found "flush", then it will appear when you create an object as a method.

`function MyObject(){};
MyObject.prototype.flush = function(){ /*another code*/ };`

`var my_object = new MyObject;
alert(my_object.flush); //return function(){}`

Expand `__proto__` property and there must be a method `flush`.

Comment: Only add that the method (or property) may not be `flush` in the first `prototype` level. As I see the prototype object `F`, or perhaps is solved by inheritance. In this case, javascript searching prototypes to the lowest level until it finds a match. If it is not found, returns `undefined`.

Comment: I was shoddy, and will add a preview of how the inheritance do not sleep in this case it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/ffmLb9wq/1/